How to extract Application versions where the files exist in Program Files/(x86) using WMI in c#?
I managed to get the file versions using the Direcotry and FileInfo. Now, I am trying to look at WMI if it can do the same process in order to decide which is the better and faster. I created the following section of code:
                            string AppToolFilter = string.Join(" OR ", Array.ConvertAll(fileNames.ToArray(), name => $"Name LIKE '%{name}.exe'"));
                            foreach (string directory in filePaths)
                            {
                                ObjectQuery AppToolquery = new ObjectQuery($"SELECT Name, Description, Version FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND (Path LIKE '{directory}%' AND Extension like 'exe') AND ({AppToolFilter})");
                                ManagementObjectSearcher AppToolsearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(_scope, AppToolquery);

                                foreach (ManagementObject AppToolObj in AppToolsearcher.Get())
                                {
                                    _IsConnected = true;

                                    stringBuilder.Append($"File Name: {AppToolObj["Name"]?.ToString().Substring(AppToolObj["Name"].ToString().LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) ?? "N/A"}; ");
                                    stringBuilder.Append($"File Description: {(AppToolObj["Description"].ToString() != null && AppToolObj["Description"].ToString().Contains("\\") ? AppToolObj["Description"]?.ToString().Substring(AppToolObj["Description"].ToString().LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) : AppToolObj["Description"]?.ToString()) ?? "N/A"}; ");
                                    stringBuilder.Append($"File Version: {AppToolObj["Version"]?.ToString() ?? "N/A"}; ");
                                }
                            }

inputs are the following:
directory paths = "C:\Program Files (x86);C:\Program Files"
applications (FileNames) = "Notepad++;PuTTY;PingInfo;Wireshark;NetTime"
_scope = new ManagementScope($"\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");

Query is the following:
SELECT Name, Description, Version FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND ((Path LIKE '\\Program Files (x86)\\%' OR Path LIKE '\\Program Files\\%') AND Extension like 'exe') AND (Name LIKE '%Notepad++.exe' OR Name LIKE '%PuTTY.exe' OR Name LIKE '%PingInfo.exe' OR Name LIKE '%Wireshark.exe' OR Name LIKE '%NetTime.exe')

Issue is that it is taking way too long to get the outputs and got Management error: Call cancelled and looking at the diagnostics session and it came out to be 43 minutes and 31 seconds.
Is there any way to improve this query to obtain the necessary outputs?

I managed to get the file versions using the Direcotry and FileInfo. Now, I am trying to look at WMI if it can do the same process in order to decide which is the better and faster...Issue is that it is taking way too long to get the outputs: Seems that you've already found the answer.

@Itallmakescents Well yes but I want to see if WMI can do it faster than Directory and FileInfo. However, I am not sure which table would be best to use; the format of WMI Query or the structure of the code.

I want to see if WMI can do it faster than Directory and FileInfo: The answer is no, WMI isn't faster.
